# Linux group keyring (eg request_key and add_key)

Tags: linux, kernel, keys

I'm working on building an application that needs to use the group keyring to share some sensitive data between processes with different owners. Whenever I try to access the group keyring (e.g."@g") using either the keyctl command or the underlying API, I get an error.

I'm guessing I have to set some kind of state to let it know *which* of my groups to get the keyring for, but documentation on this kernel feature is sparse. Anybody know how to make it work for groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the group keyring yet implemented at all? It wasn't couple of years ago, and even the kernel 3.2.9 source file `security/keys/keyctl.c` shows this:

```
    case KEY_REQKEY_DEFL_GROUP_KEYRING:
    default:
            ret = -EINVAL;
            goto error;
    }
```

and `keyctl` man page (in Fedora 16) states:

```
   (*) Group specific keyring: @g or -6

   This is a place holder for a group specific keyring, but is not actually implemented yet in the kernel.
```

Comment: That would explain things. I've been over that man page and the kernel keys documentation a lot over the last week, but that particular item slipped past me. Thanks for pointing it out.